# Search for a value in a CSV file c# WPF

Tags: c#, database, wpf, csv

[screenshot from wpf application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVDFO.png)
I'm trying to search for a value "string" in a csv file from the users input (textbox Name="searchInput").
But i keep getting the Exception? any help is appreciated.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string[] StudentArray;
string path = @"C:\Users\ogun_\Documents\PXL Programmeren\C# 
               Advanced\Studenten_toepassing.csv";

private void SearchValue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //search for a value in a csv file            
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                StudentArray = sr.ReadLine().Split(';');                   
                string searchInput = SearchTxt.Text;

                //create new view for searched data
                DataView dvSearch = dt.DefaultView;
                dvSearch.RowFilter = searchInput;
                dataGridView.ItemsSource = dvSearch;

            }
           
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Couldn't Find Data");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Exactly which exception do you get?

Comment: C# throws a *detailed* exception to help you and tell you what is wrong. Your exception handler just takes the exception, throws away all useful details and shows a generic, useless text, making debugging harder for yourself and everyone trying to help you. Don't do that. :-) Either (a) don't catch the exception at all or (b) use `catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }` instead. This should give you the details you need to find the cause of the problem. If you still need help, add the (complete) exception text to your question.

Comment: You are supposed to enter a condition in `RowFilter`, not just a text to be searched for: `LastName = 'Smith'`. See: [DataView.RowFilter Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter?view=net-5.0).

Comment: What is the exception ?

Answer (score 0):

okay i kinda got it?
but this is how i search for a value now inside the textbox Subject='SNE' and then it works its showing all students in subject 'SNE'

```
//search for a value in a csv file            
        try
        {                
             string searchInput = SearchTxt.Text;
            //How you need te search for a value is FirstName='.....'
            //How you need te search for a value is LastName='.....'
            //How you need te search for a value is Subject='.....'

            //create new view for searched data
            DataView dvSearch = dataGridView.ItemsSource as DataView;
             if (dvSearch != null)
                  dvSearch.RowFilter = SearchTxt.Text;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Couldn't Find Data");
        }
```